# How to receive device connection events from Azure IoT Hub?

Tags: azure-iot-hub

Is it possible to get notified that a device has connected to IoT hub without polling?

The only option I've found is to poll `RegisteryManager.GetDevicesAsync()` and loop through the registered devices to see if they are connected or not. I could poll, however I have no idea what sort of throttling limits exist.

That code looks like:

```
var devices = await registryManager.GetDevicesAsync(maxCountOfDevices);   
if (devices != null)
{
    foreach (var device in devices)
    {
        // do something with the connection state like
        // notify services
        device.ConnectionState
    }
}
```

What I'd like is to be able to get all registered devices, keep them in memory, and just listen for connection events.

Comment: Did you get, any other way to know the connection and disconnection. I Tried it with operation monitoring. Is also provide and event hub endpoint to read the verbose operation. So here i find the event of connection and disconnection. But now the issue is device messages and connection/disconnection events are async.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Azure IoT team suggests implementing the heartbeat pattern because connectionState is not accurate:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-identity-registry#device-heartbeat

Answer (score 0):

I Tried it with **operation monitoring** in Azure IOT Hub. It provide an event hub endpoint to read the verbose operation. So here i find the event of connection and disconnection of IOT device to IOT hub. But now the issue is device messages and connection/disconnection events are async.